# the color of the first row in gridview is not changing

Tags: c#, gridview, colors, backcolor

Ive got a gridview in asp.net webpage and the backcolor of the row is changed according to data in a specific cell, but the first row of the grid is not changing. Why is this?
Here is the code i use to change the color:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
        int StationStatus1 = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());            
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            switch (StationStatus1)
            {
                case 0:
                case 3:
                   e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;                        
                   break;                    
                case 12:                       
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;                        
                    break;
                default:
                    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    break;
```

Any help will be highly apreciated. Thanks

Comment: I believe the event is fired for every row bound, why are you looping the grid then ? Well looking again at the code you are not doing anything with the loop as such

Comment: First off, you need to completely remove the foreach loop (not its contents) - it serves no apparent purpose. And secondly, what is the color of the first row, and what is the default color (are they the same)?

Comment: I actually figured out that i did not need the foreach loop (I don't know why i added it in the first place) when i took it out it all was working fine! thanks guys.